# How does the announcer badge (and similar badges) know who shared the link?

Tags: support, badges, sharing, technical

This is probably something obvious that I just haven't noticed, but how does SO know who shared a link to a post?

The [image: Announcer], [image: Booster], and [image: Publicist] badges all seem to be able to track who shared the link.

Comment: I've wondered for a long time why there is a constant number at the end of  every share link, until I found out it is my userid which led me to realize that they're using it to track the number of visits for this purpose..

Comment: Related [meta.SE question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63684/254929).

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The share link includes your userid. My share link for your question is:

```
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274712/100297
#                               ------ ^^^^^^
```

274712 is the question id, 100297 is my userid on Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow.

Answers have similar links; the id for this answer is 274713, so the share link for this answer, customised for me, is:

```
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274713/100297
```

The only difference then with the question link is that the URL path starts with `/a` instead of `/q`.

Both link types then redirect to the full question or answer URLs:

```sh
$ curl -s -D - -o /dev/null http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274712/100297 | grep Location
Location: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274712/how-does-the-announcer-badge-and-similar-badges-know-who-shared-the-link
$ curl -s -D - -o /dev/null http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274713/100297 | grep Location
Location: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274712/how-does-the-announcer-badge-and-similar-badges-know-who-shared-the-link/274713#274713
```

The site knows what question an answer belongs to, so the URL for an answer is the same as for the parent question but with `/<answerid>#<answerid>` tacked onto the end.

Comment: Oh.  Duh.  For whatever reason I though that the second half would be the answer on the question.  This makes a lot of sense, though.

Comment: ++ finally I know how this stuff works... you need to use the SHARE instead of copy-pasting the links to get these badges...

Comment: How to disable sharing userid?

Comment: @Alex78191: by removing the last number from the URL when you share it, manually. `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274712` still works too.

Comment: It is inconvenient to delete every time.

Comment: @Alex78191: Then just don't. But there are no easier ways of getting the same URL.