# Shared popular question - no Publicist badge?

Tags: support, badges, achievements-dialog, popularity, sharing

This may be a caching issue, but was concerned it was either a bug, or ambiguity in the documentation.

Earlier today (about 5 hours prior to this post) I shared this popular SO article (which I personally just loved): [Why does HTML think “chucknorris” is a color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color?stw=2)

The share activity is [here on my Twitter feed](https://twitter.com/trnelson/status/524514129533349888)

I was not awarded the Publicist achievement for this sharing activity, but wasn't sure if this type of award takes some time to propagate or be manually approved somehow. Does anyone have any insight about the timing of these events?

Comment: Related: [How does the announcer badge (and similar badges) know who shared the link?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274712)

Comment: This is **not** off topic. It is a genuine support question; someone misunderstood a badge description and asked about it. This is exactly what Meta support questions are about. Voted to reopen.

Comment: 'no longer reproduced' is for bug reports where the system has changed and the circumstances of the bug can no longer be reproduced. Otherwise we could just close *all* answered questions with 'no longer reproduced' as the question asker now no longer has the unanswered question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The publicist badge isn't awarded for simply finding a post that's been viewed 1000 or more times and sharing it - it's for having 1000 or more unique IP addresses **visit the link you shared**. It's highly unlikely that your tweet has seen that kind of traffic in five hours.

Comment: Haha! Awesome. That makes a lot more sense. I was curious why they'd give out gold badges for such an easy task. Full disclosure: I'm running on an incredible lack of sleep and the requirements may have otherwise made complete sense to me. Thanks for your answer!