# Why does the URL from the "share" links contain the ID of the user who is sharing?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, sharing

I noticed that the URL from the "share" links on questions and answers have my user ID appended to it, even when I didn't post it.

Since removing this user ID does not break the link, I'm wondering why the site is tracking this. Is there any reputation changes or badges related to sharing links?

Comment: [Badges, badges, it's all about the badges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges)

Comment: Because this: [How does the announcer badge (and similar badges) know who shared the link?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274712)

Comment: @bluefeet badges, badges, badges, badges, badges, badges, badges, badges, badges, badges, mushroom, mushroom?

Comment: @canon snake snake, oh it's a snake.

Comment: @TimSeguine Lemonade?

Comment: @canon: And I always thought the [song](http://www.weebls-stuff.com/songs/badgers/) was about badge**r**s. Silly me...

Comment: I'm curious-you seem to have a suspicion it might have something to do with badges. Why didn't you just check? There's not that many and it would be pretty obvious from a quick scan of the badges.

Comment: @mason it only occurred to me that it could be related to reputation or badges when I was typing the question and I didn't remember that I could easily check that

Comment: This feature's pernicious effect on privacy is discussed on [Meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300472/share-links-deanonymize-user-unexpectedly), [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74274/privacy-leak-in-permalink), and (most insightfully, IMHO) [Math Meta](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2167/privacy-of-software-generated-links-to-questions-and-answers).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can earn badges for sharing links on external sites *(sites not in the SE network)*.

[announcer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/260/announcer) *"Shared a link to a question that was visited by 25 unique IP addresses. This badge can be awarded multiple times."*

[booster](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/261/booster) *"Shared a link to a question that was visited by 300 unique IP addresses. This badge can be awarded multiple times."*

[publicist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/262/publicist) *"Shared a link to a question that was visited by 1000 unique IP addresses. This badge can be awarded multiple times."*

The user ID is how the system knows that you're the sharer.

Comment: Hm, [I wonder](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277770/-1)... (Edit: Nope, still works)

Comment: @Izkata: Yes, you can give credit to another [user](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277770/500202), or remove the user ID altogether and give no-one the credit.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `-1` shouldn't exist ;)

Comment: User -1 (or any negative number) doesn't exist, but that is an optional modifier (like the question title is optional) and doesn't affect the working of the basic `http://stackoverflow.com/q/stuvwxyz` URL.  If you get the question number wrong, people go to the wrong place.  The title is functionally ignored; the user ID (referrer) is optional and if wrong is ignored.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Actually, there is a user with userId of negative 1. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1. But yea, there is no 0 user, or any other negative that I'm aware of.

Comment: Curious!  Thanks.  And my previous comment should really have been prefixed @Izkata as it was primarily a response to their second comment.

Comment: @cVplZ Pff, I assumed Community would be 0 or 1.  Meant to choose a nonexistent one.

Comment: Tor relays don't count, right? That could be used to abuse the system (repeatedly create a new identity and then browse the question many different times).

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi I don't think it's worth it to secure the link-popularity mechanism from Tor relays to protect a badge.

Comment: @hexafraction Wikipedia blocks **all** editing from Tor relays and other open proxies (even by registered users) *unless they have an IP block exemption (IPBE)*. An IPBE is very hard to get (you must be an established user with little history of abuse, and you must have a valid reason to use an open proxy to edit (such as censorship)).

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi There is no merit to having one (or more badges) that is worth circumventing an IP-based counter with a large number of proxies/Tor endpoints. A badge on its own isn't something like a malicious Wikipedia edit or a user registration--it doesn't actually damage site content or give any privs (that may be improperly earned).

Comment: @hexafraction Badges used to be totally separate from privileges, until the [meta-tag:dupehammer] was introduced. But open proxy blocking has little to do with that.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi The badges in question do not allow a user to instantly close questions as duplicates within a given tag. The dupehammer requires a gold badge in the tag, which is given by human-cast votes (for which it *is* reasonable to reverse fraud and block open proxies)

Comment: How to disable sharing userid?

Comment: I can surely say whoever comes to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277769/10785239) question are curious about the answer

Answer (score -4):

[image]

By using the ID in the shared link (Question or Answer), these badges will be awarded.

Comment: Six years ago, another user [answered this question with precisely the same information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277770/215552). What does this answer add?

Comment: @HereticMonkey That answer is saying "Shared a link to a question that was visited by 25 unique IP addresses" .what about the link to an answer :) That's my point

Comment: I would say, editing the existing answer, changing "question" to "post" would be a better route than posting a new answer with a picture.