# Does announcer badge count increase when link is opened from inside the Stack Exchange network?

Tags: discussion, badges, sharing, technical

When I write questions, answers, comments and wikis inside Stack Exchange and give a link to some other SE entry, I usually obtain the link with the `share` option. The reason is that it is bound to <kbd>L</kbd> key and I am a devoted user of keyboard shortcuts.

So, since I got to know about the shortcuts, most of my links are actually referral links.

Recently I added some links to good questions in the *FAQ* and *Recommended questions* sections in a tag wiki. At that time I didn't even know about the referring feature, and I just liked this type of links for their laconicism. This tag was created by myself a week ago, and I wrote the whole wiki from scratch.

I was accused of farming the Announcer-group badges for posting such links. So I've got several questions:

1. As far as I know, websites usually know the referring page. So, do referral links count to towards the badge score when opened from inside SE?
2. Can my choice of obtaining links be considered farming?
3. Am I morally obliged to edit already-existing links and remove the referral number?

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277769/3041194

Comment: @Dronehinge Hey, you used a referral link! =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As reported in [Announcer badge spike](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295575/209031), page referral counts are **no longer required to come from outside the SE Network**.

The most up to date place to look for badge info is [What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281615/209031)

Comment: The linked FAQ points to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298448/997587) which says the change is due to HTTPS disallowing cross-domain Referers. Does that mean it doesn't count if the click is from network site A to network site A, but only from network site A to network site B?

Answer (score 8):

1. The Announcer badge (and it's silver and gold compatriots) only count links from *outside* the Stack Exchange network.
2. Given that the default way of obtaining a link is to use the "share" option which adds your user id it can't really be described as farming - especially given point 1 above.
3. Given point 1 above whether you leave the user id in or edit it out of existing links doesn't really matter.

Comment: It's worth noting that some users disable referrer information for privacy reasons, and their in-network views *do* count. I have an Announcer badge for a link that I only ever shared in-network. This isn't very many users, though, so I still wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @JeremyBanks I've searched through Meta questions and my settings page but was not able to find an option to disable referrer information. Is that about removing userid from the URL? Then how did the referrals count?

Comment: @JeremyBanks by the way, if I publish a link outside SE, is there a way to know the traffic on that link? I'm in an opensource project and we consider posting our FAQs on SO. (If this should be a separate question, tell me and I will post it). And yes, I've read the http://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support

Comment: @NickVolynkin Sorry, I meant that the users who are clicking the links may have disabled referrer information in their browser, perhaps with an extension. Stack Exchange therefore couldn't tell that they got the links from another Stack Exchange site, and didn't know to exclude them from counting towards the badge.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Oh, that's what it is. Thank you, didn't know about this feature.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Unfortunately, Stack Exchange provides no way to know how much traffic a link gets, except for these badges. Something like that has been requested many times ([1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108738/view-analytics-for-referral-links), [2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93839/is-it-possible-to-see-how-many-people-youve-refered-to-a-question-or-answer-a), [3](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97716/display-statistics-for-question-and-answer-referrals)), but it doesn't seem like it's going to happen.

Comment: @JeremyBanks ok, then I'll just wait for a badge and divide 25 by time since publication. And answer 2 actually [has a working solution](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93853/296059).

Comment: ChrisF, it looks like Announcer counts links shared at another SE site. I just have got it likely for [referring Programmers meta post at Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31934861/how-does-halcon-calibration-works#comment51783109_31934861 "example")

Comment: @gnat - that's interesting if true. I thought that it didn't count regardless of where in the network you were.

Comment: @JeremyBanks: Now that share links generate HTTPS by default, browser policy blocking cross-site Referer header is the norm rather than requiring special configuration.

Comment: I just got a announcer badge on SO for a question in which the only reference I can find is a link I left as a comment under an answer to different SO question.  So seems that links internal to SO also count now.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I concur. I've received numerous Announcer badges in the last month or so and I don't have a habit of posting links to SO questions and answers outside of SO itself.

Comment: This is no longer correct. Since May 2017, internal link shares [now *do* count toward the badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295575/377214), and the badges were awarded retroactively.