# I announced what now? (How did I get this Announcer Badge?)

Tags: support, badges

I was just awarded the Announcer badge for a question I have never seen before:

*[Vimdiff failing with "Cannot read or write temp files"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862446/vimdiff-failing-with-cannot-read-or-write-temp-files)*

Searching the Internet for the "share" link numbers for each answer doesn't show anything.

I did receive another announcer badge recently, but that was from a share I did in my profile.

The only thing I can think of is maybe someone is manually manipulating share URLs or using a bot to do it.

Comment: I have seen this reported before where some crawler added numbers to posts, that randomly matched userids. You are just lucky. Enjoy your new badge.

Comment: Oh! The new way of saying "Thank you" to a user, awarding badges anonymously.

Comment: This has happened to me sometimes. The best hypothesis I have is that you may have linked a post in comments. Then, some scraper has copied the full content of the Q&A and your link has become successful among the users in that other site.

Comment: popular site Ars Technica is known to manipulate share Ids in a way that leads to obscure announcer badges, see eg [Strange badge award](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/6052/31260)

Comment: Why get rid of the entertaining title? Was it really that unclear?

Comment: @Mitch Is it really informative?  The purpose of titles is to tell you what the question is about without you having to read it, not to entertain you while forcing you to open up the question and read it to learn anything about what the question is asking.  If you're just looking for entertainment, there's lots of places around the net to find it.  If you can be entertaining *while still accomplishing the title's purpose* then that is of course different.

Comment: @Servy I find it informative enough to be a suitable title. Yakk seems to have found a compromise ;)

Comment: funny that [my prior comment referring "Strange badge award" discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345250/i-announced-what-now-how-did-i-get-this-announcer-badge#comment455571_345250) has got me Announcer badge

Comment: @gnat interesting. I first read your comment about Ars Technica and thought "what the hell, why do they even do that? Sounds shady". Then I followed your link and realized that they're doing this on purpose, probably to reward the user whose answer they're featuring. Which is great!

Comment: @gnat I actually got the Publicist badge through Ars (1000 visits), that's why I did research and wrote the answer you're linking to. :O

Comment: It would be nice if when the announcer badge was awarded, it told where it was linked from, not just where it linked to.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[This answer on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/697914/33047) contains the text "Duplicated on Stack Overflow" with a link `https://stackoverflow.com/a/23664167/1774667`.

1774667 is your SO userid so you are getting credited when people follow that link *.

You edited the link into the answer in revision 2 which explains where it appeared from.

<sup>*</sup> [@Ben Voigt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/103167/ben-voigt) explains in the comments that this is not "by design"

> There's more to the story, since [links from SE network sites generally
>   aren't supposed to count](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297923/does-announcer-badge-count-increase-when-link-is-opened-from-inside-stackexchang/297924#297924). But widespread deployment of HTTPS and
>   browser policy changes to not send the Referer header for cross-site
>   navigation of HTTPS links mean that links from SE sites can no longer
>   be identified and filtered out.

The link above is `http` but superuser is now `https` and the referer is not sent when clicking the link in chrome.

The exclusion of links from SE sites hasn't ever worked reliably IMO - The vast majority of the announcer badges that I personally have received are for things that I have linked elsewhere on the SE network but not externally. For example my single announcer badge on this very meta site is almost certainly from the comments I left under StackOverflow answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24796475/73226) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2481126/73226) (though the existence of scraper sites means they may end up copied externally anyway).

Comment: There's more to the story, since [links from SE network sites generally aren't supposed to count](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297924/103167).  But widespread deployment of HTTPS and browser policy changes to not send the Referer header for cross-site navigation of HTTPS links mean that links from SE sites can no longer be identified and filtered out.

Comment: @BenVoigt - I know for sure that most if not all of the times I have received the announcer badge it has been for links elsewhere on the SE network - I didn't realize that was the reason though.

Comment: @BenVoigt about 30 badges I've got at different metas ([1](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/54/announcer?userid=31260), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/74/announcer?userid=165773), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/59/announcer?userid=839601), [4](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/announcer?userid=168)) make me feel that links from SE sites count for these, as opposed to main sites. Which makes a good sense if you think of it. As opposed to main sites, meta posts are primarily intended for internal sites audience