# How to track announcer badge progression?

Tags: support, badges, badge-progress

I recently received lot of announcer badges.

I wonder if it's natural or artificial growth.

Is there a way to *see* my progression on the various links that can earn me Announcer badges?

Comment: You can't; the data that is used to award those is not public, partly to prevent gaming.

Comment: On the natural or artificial growth: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345250/i-announced-what-now-how-did-i-get-this-announcer-badge

Comment: Stack Overflow switched to HTTPS, so the referer filter for 'internal' clicks is no longer working as it is often filtered out to not leak what other HTTPS sites you visited. Result: easier to get referral badges.