# I receive wrong notifications

Tags: support, bug, badges, notifications

I have received 2 wrongs badges notifications which are not related to me:
[image]

> "You've earned the "Announcer" badge (Share a link to a question later
>   visited by 25 unique IP addresses) for ["Qt Application Icon doesn't
>   work"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813359/qt-application-icon-doesnt-work)."

and

> "You've earned the "Announcer" badge (Share a link to a question later
>   visited by 25 unique IP addresses) for ["Taking screenshots with
>   Windows Service in Windows 7"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371035/taking-screenshots-with-windows-service-in-windows-7)."

I have no relation to these questions and answers. How the problem can be solved?

Comment: Either you or someone else shared a link with your ID attached to it. I don't see how this "problem" should be resolved. Prevent someone else from posting a link? Good luck.

Comment: @Tom But maybe it's a real bug? How do you know someone used OP's account and posted a link?

Comment: @MarounMaroun Because that's how the share link works. Btw here is your own for this question here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/353720/1735406. Feel free to create a Meta Post about the Announcer badge you may get.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345250/i-announced-what-now-how-did-i-get-this-announcer-badge

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34993846/how-can-i-capture-the-screen-from-a-windows-service and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34913527/how-to-set-an-application-icon-in-qt/34913730#34913730 for places you linked to those