# Why does a question URL append the question title?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, seo

An example question URL is `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36032064/make-ftp-server-return-files-listed-by-timestamp-with-apache-ftpclient`. But even with a random text replacing the title, the question is identified correctly. Is this text actually part of the question URL? Or it is just added in client side (by browser) to make it more readable?

Comment: I guess it is to help easily search the question in your browser history. (Provided you don't use incognito)

Comment: It's at least not necessary. You can access a question with a URL in the style of `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319610` even. In fact, that's what you'll get from the "share" link, minus the user id appended to the end.

Comment: You might also be interested in who the best user ever is http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2270563/TheBestUserONEARTH

Comment: Probably off-topic for META - WebMasters.SE would be much better place to ask SEO question.

Comment: @Kendra Yeah! i read about that here... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277769/2270563

Comment: Keywords being "slug" and "SEO".

Comment: The text is ignored by the site (Maybe not ignored in terms of tracking visitors, but it doesn't change the functionality of the URL). It helps with SEO and also provides a human-readable URL. It's a common technique used by many many sites. The text isn't added client side - it's sent from the server, but that doesn't really change anything

Answer (score 3):

The question title won't affect the system. You can type anything after the question ID, it won't matter. But why is it there?

- for Search Engine Optimization (SEO) reasons.

Search engines go through millions of pages searching for your search term. When a part of your term matches with a part of the url there's a good chance that it may contain what you are looking for.

- Bookmarks and Browser history (User Experience)

One of the major reasons for using the url binded parameters are because it's easier for the user to get back to his/her saved bookmark, or the post he/she visited few weeks ago by searching through the browser's history/bookmarks. Furthermore browsers will always assist you by matching your history and bookmarks when you type something in the url bar.

- help user to decide whether it is the needed post.

Another reason is that if we share a link to a post without the title there's no way to know what kind of post that is. For an example, someone who knows about `apache 
ftpclient` may decide to take a look at this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36032064/make-ftp-server-return-files-listed-by-timestamp-with-apache-ftpclient`.