# Highest-rated answer is always given the number "1858225"?

Tags: discussion, permalink

I've noticed that the "share" link for the highest-rated answer on a SO or meta SO question (but not questions on other sites!) always ends with "/1858225". Is this intentional? Why does it happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your user ID is https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1858225/kyle-strand

> ```
>                                                ^^^^^^^ it's your UserId
> ```

There are badges you can earn for sharing post links on other sites outside of SE network sites. So the way they know you shared the link is they append your User ID to the end of the link.

For more info, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274713/3041194

> ```
>                                                     ^^^^^^^^ see that's my userId
> ```

There could be two reasons it's not doing it on other sites:

1) You aren't logged into that site. You have to be logged in for it to append your userId.

2) If you are logged in to a different site (and not the meta of the same main site which is the same UserId) you will almost certainly have a different UserId for that site, since like you said, UserId's are not consistent across sites. So it would append a different number than 1858225 on that site, which would be whatever your UserId is for that site.

Comment: Ah. In that case, I'm sure this question is a duplicate; I just didn't find the original because I stupidly searched for "1858225".

Comment: Also, user IDs aren't consistent across sites anyway.

Answer (score 5):

That's your user ID (1858225) at the end of the share link. Mine is 62576, as you can see here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296117/62576. It's for tracking the number of times you've linked to different things; there's a badge (can't recall the name for it offhand) for advertising. It counts both for off-site use of the link as well as when posting here for related questions.

It actually has nothing to do with the *highest rated answer*. You'll notice it on any of the permalinks you get by using the `share` link, even the lowest rated ones. It's simply your user ID appended to the end of the link to track who shared it.

Comment: Apparently I discovered this during a binge of highest-rated-answer link-sharing. Confirmation bias, I guess--reminds me of the 2-4-6 task.