# Can I find out how I got an Announcer badge?

Tags: support, badges

A little while ago I received a notification that I was awarded the Announcer badge for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388753/how-to-get-output-from-subprocess-popen). I've kept my Stack Exchange participation separate from social media, so - although it is a rather old question - I'm reasonably certain I'd remember sharing a link to it, if I had.  However, I don't remember publicizing the question, and why would I? I didn't ask it and didn't provide an answer. So, was I given this badge in error? If not, is there any way to find out how/when I shared the link?

Comment: You get the announcer badge for posting a link to the question anywhere, not necessarily social networks. You may have referred to that question on some comment as well.

Comment: If you can, analyze your comments to find which one was it!

Comment: @anshabhi if the referrer is stackoverflow.com that doesn't count as a shared link for the announcer badge.

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [Why did I just get the Announcer Badge and the Booster badge?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145673/165773) See also: [How does the announcer badge (and similar badges) know who shared the link?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274712/839601)

Comment: I did some investigating by searching on google. I couldn't find any site external or internal where you shared a link to that question or any of it's undeleted answers. So wherever you/someone else posted that link, google didn't index it. Or maybe it's bug.

Comment: The post was mentioned here [here](https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8/issues/68), [here](https://github.com/peritus/geocommit/blob/master/src/geocommit/util.py), [here](http://pydoc.net/Python/geocommit/0.9.2/geocommit.util/), [here](http://www.science-emergence.com/Python/HowToUseFortranWithPython/_source/), and [many other places](https://www.google.ca/search?q=stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F1388753). It seems like a very popular post, and you would have to search through all of the results to find which one you posted. I do think that this would be a good feature request though.

Comment: @rene: there are several sites that publish SO data dumps i.e., you might get the announcer badge even if all your links were originally published only on SO.

Comment: Proposed duplicate https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359167/why-did-i-just-get-the-announcer-badge has an answer with a useful SEDE query ... which however doesn't work for me at the moment.

Answer (score 21):

It has often been the case that other people and organisations will use the sharing links already published when they publicise a link. It has also been know for them to append a random (or perhaps not so random) number which happens to be someone's user id. This gives you (the random user) a free badge.

There's no way of finding where these links were shared other than searching the entire internet via Google <sup>*</sup>.

*<sup>* other search engines are available</sup>*

Comment: _"It has also been know for them to append a random (or perhaps not so random) number which happens to be someone's user id"_ Really? o.O Why would anyone do that?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - no idea. Perhaps they know it gives the announcer badge and want to be nice to someone. I do know that this has been done. I can't find/remember where it was done right now, but it might come to me.

Comment: It could be they are appending a random number each time the link is generated to ensure it is not pulled from cache.

Comment: @Brianfromstatefarm, it is still strange. The common practice to avoid cache is using a query string, so it would be better to add: `?v=random-number`

Comment: I came to this thread with the exact same question as the OP. Too bad that SE doesn't store the referrer of each visit, it would be nice to know which link cased the badge.

Answer (score 8):

There is not an easy way to find how you've earned that. You or someone else have shared a link with your User ID. Every time someones visits Stack Overflow with a link that has your User ID and *the referrer is not another Stack Overflow page*, it will count towards you.

As you don't remember posting it in a Blog, Twitter or Facebook, probably someone else has done that. ChrisF [suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299604/1476885) that some people takes links and manually add Users IDs. I believe that this is very rare.

What I believe is that you have clicked in the "share" button (that appends your User ID to the link) and added this to a comment. Someone else clicked in the link, liked the question and shared it with your User ID out of SO.

I've created a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/338158/436487/see-in-which-comment-ive-linked-to-a-question) to search your comments and confirm that. Unfortunately, none of the 26 times that you've done that (SO, MSO, MSE) links to this specific question. However, I still believe that it makes sense and probably the question was deleted and took your comment with it.

Comment: It isn't really that rare. I came across a site a few months back that had my recent questions on it, as well as a ton of others. It even copied comments to the question as if it were posted there.

Comment: @EvanCarslake, so they have copied the entire question. You'll not get an announcer badge even if the site redirects to SO. What I'm saying that is rare is when a site copies a SO link and adds your user id to it. In this case you would get the badge for redirects.