# Why did I just get the announcer badge?

Tags: discussion, bug, badges

I commented on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8472462/2642059

That comment doesn't have a link, yet I strangely earned the [announcer badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/260/announcer) for that comment today.

Not that I'm complaining about a free badge... but seems like a bug???

Comment: Weird. I also have a small number of these recently for questions that I don't remember linking to, and I don't remember getting notifications for them.

Comment: I wonder if the link *in the question* was awarded the badge and you, being a commentor, were somehow awarded the badge instead. The person who posted the answer does not have this badge

Comment: I tried searching for https://stackoverflow.com/q/7053818/2642059 (the link with your user ID), but that doesn't get me any hits. So if that version of the link was used, it wasn't on a public space...

Comment: You probably shared a link to the question or to one of its answers but don't remember doing so.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299604/2394254

Comment: @S.L.Barth searching on Google for it doesn’t return the superuser page where it is contained. I don’t think you can reliably find inward links like that.

Comment: also related (feature request): https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94212/364344

Comment: -1 for not for not reading what an announcer badge is.

Comment: @jpmc26 Why did you get that impression? They do know what the announcer badge is - they just didn't think it was working as advertised as the only interaction they can apparently remember is leaving a comment on the question and this is not supposed to give you the badge.

Comment: I got 30 announcer badges since this jumped off the rails.  Somewhere around late spring of this year, judging from the award dates.  A 300% increase in just 5 months.  Memory is fickle, but some of them I *know* I never linked.  I'm guessing I'm getting awarded for other people's links.

Comment: @HansPassant - Have you an example? You could try this SEDE query to see if it does find something http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/756227/possible-links-i-left-to-a-question-on-se-network?QuestionId=7053818&UserId=2642059

Comment: @MartinSmith Because they thought they got an announcer badge for leaving a comment on one of the answers at the question, not for leaving a link to the question/answer somewhere. If they knew what it was, then even thinking that in the first place doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @jpmc26 yes that would not be the correct behaviour if they got that badge for that action. Hence why they reported it as a bug.

Comment: @jpmc26, you are misunderstanding what the person is asking. They fully understand what the announcer badge is for and indicate so in their question. However, the person is claiming to have been given  the badge even though they did not leave a link to it. However, it appears likely that they just forgot that they had linked to it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You linked to that question on [this comment on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/201291/is-there-any-free-diff-file-viewer/232724#comment1655089_232724) using the URL `http://stackoverflow.com/q/7053818/2642059`

[image]

So presumably the visitors that got you the badge came from there.

In network links aren’t supposed to count but this hasn’t worked correctly for some time due to lack of referer information being passed.

NB: In your case I found this manually but you could also use an SEDE query.

The one below searches all posts and all comments on sites you are a member. It will only search posts/comments left by you for performance reasons.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/756514/possible-links-i-left-to-a-question-on-se-network?PostId=7053818&UserId=2642059

Comment: How did you find that comment? SEDE?

Comment: @grgarside no I just looked at sites on the OP’s profile where such a  link might feasibly be. Superuser was the second one I looked at and easy to scan down and see it https://superuser.com/users/242502/jonathan-mee?tab=activity and I knew it couldn’t be SO itself as there is no “Linked questions” panel.

Comment: Goodness, I'm impressed with your research.

Comment: Thanks for the SEDE query, but it's giving me massive errors. Did something change in SEDE? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/47482919#47482919

Comment: Presumably they have removed the permissions for sp_executesql. I have no idea why. In general this might be done as SQL injection measure but as the whole point of that site is to run user supplied arbitrary queries that doesn't seem like it should be a concern here.

Comment: You could replace use of that with EXEC('') instead. The string to execute would need a USE in it to set the database context

Answer (score 6):

You don't get this badge for sharing a link in a comment, but you get it for sharing the link of the question from the `share` button like:

[image]

So, you probably shared that answer, like you did in this question, and that is why you got that Badge.

**Edit:** The `Announcer` badge is awarded when you share a question or any of its answer. Because when you press the `share` button you get your `user id` attached to the url. So, it is not necessarily awarded only by pressing the `share` button on the question. Also, check this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299604/2394254

Comment: The badge is only [awarded](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/260/announcer?userid=2642059) for sharing **questions**, not answers. Your point partially stands though.

Comment: @Justastudent I don't think so, read my updated answer.

Comment: That may be, it's just that the badge description says that "Share a link to a **question** later visited by 25 unique IP addresses.". I agree with the rest of your answer.

Comment: @Justastudent Incorrect. Sharing an answer counts towards this as well. Both questions and answers are linked off their ID, and if you're logged in it appends your user ID to the end, which is how you get credit

Comment: @Machavity In that case the badge description needs to be updated, but that's a separate issue. Just for completeness, are you aware of anyone having received the badge for linking to an answer, not a question?

Comment: @Justastudent I did for an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/260/announcer?userid=2370483) I made a few years ago

Comment: I opened a separate [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359180) for the description update. Hope you don't mind me using you as an example, @Machavity.