# Can the Announcer, Booster and Publicist badge descriptions be updated to be complete?

Tags: feature-request, badges, help-center

<sup>This request is sparked by a very recent [exchange](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359167/why-did-i-just-get-the-announcer-badge#comment530983_359170) in comments.</sup>

The description of the [Announcer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/260/announcer) badge currently reads:

> Share a link to a question later visited by 25 unique IP addresses.

The [Booster](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/261/booster) and [Publicist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/262/publicist) badges are similar, with different numbers (300 and 1000, respectively).

As [Machavity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2370483/machavity) [embodies](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/260/announcer?userid=2370483), the badge can however also be awarded for a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5016587/7) to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15707789).

I therefore propose to update the descriptions of the above tags to read:

> Share a link to a question **or answer** later visited by *X* unique IP addresses.

Where *X* would of course be 25, 300 or 1000, respectively. Proposed change in bold, I am *not* proposing to have bold face text in the badge description.

The badges can also be acquired by sharing links to comments, but those take the form of a question link (`[link to question]#comment[comment id]_[post id]`) anyway, so I think those count as links to questions. Mentioning links to comments for completeness as well would be nice though.

---

Alternatively, it could be made clear that links to answers and comments resolve to (and count as) links to questions. Exact phrasing aside, something like the following could work:

> Share a link to a question later visited by *X* unique IP addresses.
>   Links to answers and comments on a question page count as linking to that question.

Of course, suggestions for an improved phrasing are welcome!

Comment: I'm not sure Machavity's theory jives with [the actual requirements around the badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188733/175248).  They could've left a link to it using the short-hand link, and someone picked up on it over time.  I don't disagree that it's a bit...confusing how  "outside of the network" is determined, though.

Comment: No, as far as I know, you don’t get a badge for linking the answer, but when someone follows your link to an answer, they are also visiting the question. In other words, you are linking to a question when you publish a link to one of its answers (or comments).

Comment: @Holger, thus, you (indirectly) get a badge for linking an answer. What you're saying is correct and it made sense to me when I thought about it for a bit while writing up this request, but it's somewhat confusing that it's not mentioned in the badge description, IMHO.

Comment: It would be more confusing to bring answers into that sentence, as the end, you get the badge for the link to the question, with all consequences, i.e. all visits to one question accumulate, regardless of which link the users follow and you can get the badge only once per question. Note that [Machavity’s badge stats](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/260/announcer?userid=2370483) also points to the linked question, not an answer.

Comment: Fair enough, @Holger. So how about this proposal: add a sentence to the description mentioning that linking to answers and comments indirectly links to the question they are under, and thus counts towards this badge? It may just be me, but I don't like that this implicit behavior is not documented at the moment.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable proposal

Comment: Thanks @Holger, I have included that in the question now. The request still stands as 'this needs to be documented', the exact way of documenting this is now more open.