# Does Stack Exchange have any affiliation program?

Tags: discussion, support

I want to know whether Stack Exchange has any(or previously used to have any) affiliation program?

Some people, in some other forums, were asking whether Stack Exchange has any sort of affiliation facility.

I made a search over here, but could not find any fruitful result.

Here's my search results.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=affiliation+program

Comment: Well, directing users to questions via specially-formatted links can provide you with badges.

Comment: Please, can you explain? @TZHX

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no affiliation programme.

Such a programme would not make any sense. There is nothing being sold here, all content is freely available.

You can, at best, earn badges by sharing links. Each post has a *share* link underneath that gives you a [unique URL](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274712/how-does-the-announcer-badge-and-similar-badges-know-who-shared-the-link). If enough people click on that URL from outside to visit, you are given badges. That's it.