# Shortening short SE link even more

Tags: support, hyperlinks, sharing

When I click `share` on a SE question, I get a link of the form:

`http://stackoverflow.com/q/40464715/122687`

But since I often need to paste in instant messaging or source code comments, I want it to be as short as possible, so I strip the `/122687` part out and the link still works.

Can I rely on this continuing to work on the future, or am I setting myself up for problems?

My question applies not only to question links, but also to answer links such as `http://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/122687` where I remove the last part again, and it still works.

Comment: `//stackoverflow.com/q/40464715` to have it even shorter. The last part is your user id, so that it counts towards the announcer badges. See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274712/how-does-the-announcer-badge-and-similar-badges-know-who-shared-the-link

Comment: @Tunaki That won't work (reliably) in instant messaging or source code comments. Or emails, since some clients (Outlook) use `file:///` when detecting protocol-relative URLs.

Comment: Shoulda gotten in on this whole deal sooner to get a shorter user id. Mine is a whole 3 characters shorter… ;-P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, these links will continue to work without the user ID number on the end. The user ID is completely optional and only used for tracking the Announcer badge class - you will never be required to include it as that requirement would break short links for users who do not have an account on the site (try viewing a question in incognito - you get the same link without the second number).